# Magento - Base table or view not found:Table 'review_entity_summary' doesn't exist

Tags: magento

I have uploaded Magento website from localhost to server. But after uploading it throwing following errors

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'review_entity_summary' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `review_entity_summary`.* FROM `review_entity_summary` WHERE (entity_pk_value IN('31', '47', '46', '45', '44', '43', '42', '41', '40', '38', '35', '34')) AND (entity_type = 1) AND (store_id = '1')
```

Can anybody tell how to fix this (OR how to create these tables)

Comment: Show your code where it is throwing the error

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like one of your core tables is missing or has not been migrated correctly.

If you don't care about losing your reviews do the following.

Drop all the review tables in your database:

```
review
review_detail
review_entity
review_entity_summary
review_status
review_store
```

Navigate to this folder:
app/code/core/Mage/Review/sql/review_setup

And re-run all the setup scripts.

Unfortunately they appear to be bundled within the core installation so you'll need to edit the sql to run in directly replacing:

```
{$this->getTable('review')}
```

with

```
review
```

for each one.

> You may need to disable FK and re-enable them if they have any
>   dependencies/you have custom tables.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the table "review_entity_summary" in your new instance and if it is not present then some custom installer/upgrade script has deleted this table.

To fix this problem you need for first figure it out how it got deleted and them apply fix accordingly. Maybe you can simply create this table mannually from your localhost (with/without data) for the quick fix.